# mapr: Install mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0 manually

Tags: linux, apache-zookeeper, mapr

I want to install `mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0.32987` through `commandline` manually, but when i provide version to yum install `mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0.32987`, it's giving me No package available error.

How to install mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0 since i can't use `"yum install mapr-zookeeper"` since it will install `mapr-zookeeper-5.1.0`

Comment: ? May be change repo to 5.0.0 http://archive.mapr.com/releases/v5.0.0/redhat/ ... Or alternatively download mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0.32987.GA-1.x86_64.rpm , and install with # `cd Downloads/ && yum install ./mapr-zookeeper-5.0.0.32987.GA-1.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

Just download

http://archive.mapr.com/releases/v5.0.0/redhat/mapr-zk-internal-5.0.0.32987.GA.v3.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm

and

http://archive.mapr.com/releases/v5.0.0/redhat/mapr-zk-internal-5.0.0.32987.GA.v3.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm

and install using rpm

```
rpm -i mapr-zk-internal-5.0.0.32987.GA.v3.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm mapr-zk-internal-5.0.0.32987.GA.v3.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm
```